How to determine correct Gradle Wrapper version from Java Version in Flutter?
Lets say, as a Flutter developer, we have (arbitrarily chosen) Java version 20 installed on our machine.
So we want to know what version of the Gradle Wrapper to set in android/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties such that it will be compatible with our Java version.
So we go to the compatibility matrix.
Should we use the "Support for Toolchains" or "Support for running Gradle" version number for the Gradle version?
and WHY?
